# why listFragment will automatically Resize

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard, android-listfragment

My UI Layout is like this;

[image: Layout]

My question is, when the screen has enough space for FrameLayout's ListFragment's Fragment,
the ListFragment will be fully displayed. but if the screen is too small, ListFragment will be automatically compressed and cannot be fully displayed their contents.

I look forward to the effect is that if the screen is too small, scroll bars will appear, rather than changing the height of ListFragment.

Comment: The trouble with `ListView` in a vertically expandable space (like a `ScrollView`) is that `ListView` has no Idea of how many Items it's going to show and how much height it should take. If it expands to show all items, its no longer a `ListView` in visual sense.

Comment: @wingman Thank you for your answer, i want to display a List of all the Item, what is the right layout?I do not know exactly how much item.

Comment: Don't place `ListView` like controls in a `ScrollView`. Make everything else's height `wrap content`, and make `ListFragment`'s height `fill parent`. If layout is still congested, Consider placing some of the elements under a separate tab, or use a popup to show elements in full detail.

Comment: In fact, ScrollView is because of the UI needs to move up when softkeyboard shown. If remove the ScrollView, can i get the same effect when skb show?

Comment: Soft keyboard generally doesn't leaves a sensible space to squeeze in full layouts. View focus order is used to jump between editable views in layout. So I'd recommend letting the system handle such situations.

Comment: uh,ok,Android is not friendly to developers.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the response of S.D, I have had the same problem with the `ScrollView` and `ListFragment`, the list always has the same height despite it is forced on the layout. Leaving the FrameLayout out of the `ScrollView` this problem disappears.
In your case, could be a good idea make your `View` a custom `ListView` where each item will be different. First item could be the first `TextBox`, the second item will be the first `Fragment`, and so on. 
I hope that this response be helpful to you.